# Entity Framework: why “virtual” will by default be lazy-loaded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

With EF code first "[Association properties that are marked as “virtual” will by default be lazy-loaded](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database)".

Is it by convention or there is a logic behind this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on Virtual methods? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: Yes of course and?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious... The EF uses proxy classes to track state and do other magic. By making the properties Virtual, you give it an opportunity to add a custom implementation to the property that triggers the loading. From the first sentence of the documentation `The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class.`

Comment: Not "it must be overriden". And sure, we can all build something that lazy loads without using overrides, but can you develop something that lazy loads _without changing the signature of the class or method_. By that I mean your NonLL type and your LL type can be used interchangeably in code (so not just an identical signature but also the compiler believing they're exchangeable types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By marking the property as virtual allows EF to override it in the derived proxy class it wraps around your object. This allows EF to add a loading hook in the overridden property, and enables the lazy loading behaviour.

Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

The default Entity Framework behaviour is, where possible, to lazy load releated objects. This can be disabled by simply turning off lazy loading for the context, or for individual entities (see link above):

For example, to disable lazy loading for a context:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: So this is a convention... A convention that have a logic explanation but only because EF works like this. Good to know...